# Why doesn't my program work if I comment out a member's constructor call?

Tags: c#, constructor, stringbuilder, default-constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Test
    {
        public StringBuilder a;

        /*public Test()
        {
            a = new StringBuilder();
        } */
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test testobj = new Test();
            testobj.a.Append("Hello");
            Console.WriteLine(testobj.a);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Shouldn't the default constructor for Test Class call every default constructor for every file in the class?

Comment: Your code snippet will work only if commented part is not. I see no error here.

Comment: Each field in the class is created with the default value, and default for classes is null.

Comment: No, the default constructor will never do that.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I meant that by commenting it doesn't work

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have a C++ background. You need to make sure that you understand object references in C# better. `a` is of reference type and is `null` initialized by default.

Comment: You're right. I come from C++. Thank you! I'll delve better object references

Comment: @PaoloVeneziani in C# think of everything that is a `class` type as being wrapped up in a hidden `unique_ptr` and everywhere you are using a `.` with a `class` type you are really doing a `->`

Comment: @PaoloVeneziani oops, that example should have said `shared_ptr` not `unique_ptr`. Also don't take the analogy too far, smart pointers use reference counting to get immediate cleanup, in C# the GC does the cleanup at it's own pace.